# Endpoint on Dynamics NAV needs IE trigger

Tags: service, microsoft-dynamics, endpoint, navision

I have a windows service running that communicates with a Dynamics NAV endpoint. Once this service is (re)started, the NAV endpoint responds with a "The login failed when connecting to sql server".

If I then paste the URL for the endpoint to Internet Explore (on the server hosting the service), then endpoint service responds correctly. From now on my window service works well, and does not fail.

So it seems that IE triggers an open connection that the service followingly can use.

Any idea what could be wrong here, and why it works after calling the endpoint in IE?

Comment: sorry but we need more information...what is this " windows service running that communicates with a Dynamics NAV endpoint"?

Comment: The Windows service performs a System.Web.Request to a Navision endpoint. The endpoint could look like

http://dwis-test011.dynamic-systems.lan:7047/DynamicsNAV70/WS/CRONUS%20International%20Ltd/Codeunit/DWWebService.

The response back from this request is the error message "the login failed when connecting to sql server..."

If I paste the URL of the endpoint to IE explore (on the server hosting the windows service), then I no longer get error message from endpoint (webservice), but get the proper result. As if IE opens the connection, and the windows service takes it over... 

BR